# How to make dynamic picture boxes with text on bottom with css?

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I want to make a dynamic picture boxes in css that has text on the bottom like the picture below.
by dynamic I mean that when I minimize the window it will be on different rows and not in one long row.
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aligning images in a row with text below each image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747377/aligning-images-in-a-row-with-text-below-each-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use floated containers with centrally aligned images and text inside. When you reduce viewport size images that don't fit the new width will be shifted bellow.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pLdaS/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="container">
    <li><img src="" width="100" height="100" alt="" />Comment #1</li>
    <li><img src="" width="100" height="100" alt="" />Comment #2</li>
    <li><img src="" width="100" height="100" alt="" />Comment #3</li>
    <li><img src="" width="100" height="100" alt="" />Comment #4</li>
    <li><img src="" width="100" height="100" alt="" />Comment #5</li>
    <li><img src="" width="100" height="100" alt="" />Comment #6</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style:none;
}

.container li {
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0.4em;
}

.container img {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called responsive design. There are couple of frameworks that does this. I would recommend checking some of them. I personally like BootStrap CSS framework and their code may help you figure this out.

http://getbootstrap.com/

The logic will most likely use margin. You can check margin as well for CSS layouts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this feature, it means you are looking for a responsive design. A design which will change the appearance of the page when the site size changes.

My advice is to use a responsive framework. There are many issues and problems which needs to be considered, and using a framework can help you a loot!

Here are some of them

- www.yamel.de
- foundation.zurb.com
- purecss.io